# Can I leverage having my app engine and storage in the same bucket?

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, google-bucket

I have an app engine instance which needs to read frequently from my storage (using http). The files on storage are updated very frequently so it's not relevant to deploy them with the app.

I can't see any way to leverage the "proximity" of having the app and resources in the bucket. Is there a way to gain an advantage.
By leverage/advantage I mean saving costs, saving time, etc. Thanks!

Comment: Your app files are pulled from the bucket if App Engine needs to create an instance. I'm unsure whether these retrievals are charged (but assume that they are). You could update the app files directly in the Cloud Storage bucket as they change but this could be problematic (there's no way to ensure every instance is using the same files nor to apply a transactional update if you need to ensure that multiple files are updated at once). The conventional solution **is** to use a(nother) Cloud Storage bucket (in the same region as the app) for files like this.

Comment: There is no leverage to be gained.  Any bucket in the same region is fine and very inexpensive.

Comment: Omri, do let me know if the below information in the answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an app, App Engine creates a default bucket that provides the first 5GB of storage for free. The default bucket also includes a free quota for Cloud Storage I/O operations. See [Pricing, quotas, and limits](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/using-cloud-storage?tab=python#pricing_quotas_and_limits) for details. You will be charged for storage over the 5GB limit.You can make use of this bucket when performing the l/O operations as per your requirement to read from these resources.

The name of the default bucket is in the following format:
`project-id.appspot.com`

Also as mentioned in the comments above by DazWilkin you may try to make use of another Cloud Storage bucket (in the same region as the app) for reading operations.